# How to use thousand separator in NSString

Tags: ios, nsstring

NSString just like "1000.00" and "1008977.72",

how can I format them to "1,000.00" and "1,008,977.00"

That's my question, and help me with this, thank you in advance.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

I did that not a long age. Here's the code:

```
NSNumberFormatter *numberFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[numberFormatter setGroupingSeparator:@","];
[numberFormatter setGroupingSize:3];
[numberFormatter setUsesGroupingSeparator:YES];
[numberFormatter setDecimalSeparator:@"."];
[numberFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
[numberFormatter setMaximumFractionDigits:2];
NSString *theString = [numberFormatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:1008977.72]];
```

Hope it helps

---

**EDIT**

As *[Olie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/34820/olie)* asked I'll post a code that will use current locale settings to set grouping/decimal separators itself.

```
NSNumberFormatter *numberFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[numberFormatter setLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];
[numberFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
[numberFormatter setMaximumFractionDigits:2];
NSString *theString = [numberFormatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:1008977.72]];
NSLog(@"The string: %@", theString);
```

Using `[NSLocale localeWithLocaleIdentifier:]` instead of `[NSLocale currentLocale]` gave me the following results:

```
[NSLocale localeWithLocaleIdentifier:@"be_NL"]
The string: 1 008 977,72
[NSLocale localeWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_GB"]
The string: 1,008,977.72
[NSLocale localeWithLocaleIdentifier:@"DE"]
The string: 1.008.977,72
[NSLocale localeWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"]
The string: 1,008,977.72
```

Comment: That's pretty good, but I'll up-vote your answer if you edit to show how to get the grouping separator for the local (*i.e.*, USA uses "," while most of Europe uses "." as the thousand separator, and vice versa for the decimal separator.)

Comment: @Olie I hope I did it right. Didn't touch any Objective-C for quite a while now :-)

Comment: Had to add [formatter setMinimumFractionDigits:2]; to make it work for me.

Answer (score 1):

Just translated in Swift:

```
    let formatter = NumberFormatter()
    formatter.groupingSeparator = ","
    formatter.groupingSize = 3
    formatter.usesGroupingSeparator = true
    formatter.decimalSeparator = "."
    formatter.numberStyle = .decimal
    formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 2
    formatter.minimumFractionDigits = 2
    formatter.minimumIntegerDigits = 1
    let result = formatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: value)) ?? "0.00"
```